# why do I get an error in google apss script "You cannot schedule a event in the past"

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

I'm trying to figure out how to make a one-time trigger for a function in a google apps script.

Basically I want to be able to schedule an event to happen lets say tomorrow at 2PM. I don't want it to be a recurring event(I see all documentation from google is about recurring events).

I keep receiving this error `Exception: You cannot schedule an event in the past. (line 17, file "Code"`

Any explanation/help welcome.

```
function trigger(){

var rawdate = "2020-07-29T11:30";

var time = rawdate.substr(11).split(':');
var durationMilliseconds = time[0] * 3600000 + time[1] * 60000;
var year = rawdate.substr(0,4);
var month = rawdate.substr(5,2);
var date = rawdate.substr(8,2);

ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .atDate(year, month, date)
  .after(durationMilliseconds)
  .inTimezone("America/New_York")
  .create();
}
```

Comment: The `atDate()` method shouldn't be used if the `after()` method is being used.  I'm guessing that the `atDate()` method is being evaluated first, and because you are using today's date, it's evaluating the date as being today, just after midnight at the start of the day, which is in the past.  Today at time 00:00 is in the past.  The `after()` method doesn't add time to the `atDate()` method.  The `after()` method automatically determines what the current timestamp is at the time of it's creation, and then goes from there.

Comment: Got it, any ideas how to create what I want off a date and time stamp. How do I schedule an event for a time in the future? (I'm getting the input from a user in html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. You just need to calculate the **difference** in hours between the scheduled (trigger) datetime and the current datetime. Then, you will add the hours difference to the .after() method:

```
function trigger(){

// Set here the date you want to schedule the one-time trigger
var rawdate = "2020-07-29T21:30";
var today_D = new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"}));
var scheduled_D = new Date(rawdate);
var time_af = Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;

ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
.timeBased()
.after(time_af * 60 *60 * 1000)
.create();
}
```

Now you don't need:

- `.inTimezone("America/New_York")` since the hours difference start
  from the correct timezone,
- `.atDate()` since the script will automatically calculate the amount
  of hours after the script will run based on the scheduled date.

Last but not least, *rawdate* can be passed directly to the new Date() object:

```
new Date(rawdate)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it, but it only does hours, can you modify your answer to include minutes. Also will it be a problem if let's say I schedule it for a week later, will any issue come from a big millisecond number?

Comment: @jack I edited my answer. It now considers minutes as well. time_af returns a decimal number now and thus it contains minutes.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", ...))` is fraught. Implementations are not required to parse the output of *toLocaleString*, and may not, for obvious reasons.